# stop service created in the last opening

Tags: android, service, background-process

I created a service to start when my activity is destroyed, Ok.
I closed my app and the service is running normally but when i open my app again, I call the stopservice but the service don't finish.

How to stop the service created in the last application opening?

Comment: Please provide enough information to reproduce this issue. Code are always welcome

Comment: make your question more clear !!

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score 0):

Here,i put some snippet of code which is helpful to you.you can stop service using unbind-service.

```
protected ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceConnected");
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
}
```

}

```
public void start() {
// mContext is defined upper in code, I think it is not necessary to explain what is it 
mContext.bindService(i, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
mContext.startService(i);
```

}

```
public void stop() {
mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, ServiceRemote.class));
mContext.unbindService(mServerConn);
```

}